# UITableView inside of ViewController goes behind nav bar on certain iPhones

Tags: ios

So, in the app, I put an empty view behind the navbar and my UITableView inside of a View to try to accommodate with the spacing.

This worked great on the 5s, but on the 6s there is a huge white space.

How can I fix this?

Here is the iPhone 6s:

[image: iPhone 6s]

And here is the iPhone 5s:

[image: iPhone 5s]

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @BhavukJain yes, I am.

Comment: I'm going concur with @BhavukJain's implication - you're using auto layout wrong. Check your vertical constraints for your `TableView`, specifically the ones binding it to the upper position. Post a screenshot if you need further help.

Comment: Untick constrain to margins and then add constraints. Might help.

Comment: @jped: Hi. Just reviewing answer history over the last week. Did you find any of the below answers useful?

Comment: @devim1 The other developer I work with ended up fixing the issue, so I didn't end up using these answers. Nor do I remember how he fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

@jped:  (1) Select the TableView inside the Storyboard (2) At the bottom-right of the storyBoard are four icons[image: Icons to use for AutoLayout].

(3) 2nd from the right is one that looks like a Tie-Fighter (excuse the comparison). It opens a popup to allow you to add constraints. The one at the Top (align to top) is the most crucial for you to avoid this large gap between different phones sizes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, our other developer ended up fixing it somehow, but I'll refer to this next time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check

1.Constraints to margin is unchecked.

2.Top and bottom spacing for table view is relative to its superview(not the top and bottom layout guide).